# What's the minimum discharge voltage for a 12 V LiFePO₄ battery?

Tags: voltage, batteries, discharge, lifepo4, over-discharge

I just purchased two "SOK LiFePO<sub>4</sub> 12 V batteries". One of them, after opening the box, had a voltage of 7.9 V, the other was at 12.9 V. They haven't been used at all.

What's the minimum safe discharge voltage for this kind of battery? Should I be worried about the one that came at 7.9 V? I am not very experienced with batteries, I assumed they would come new at very nearly identical voltages to be ready to be connected in series.

I am not sure if I should return it, or buy a 12 V charger.

[image: Out of the box]

Comment: According to this [datasheet](https://www.sokbattery.com/media/sparsh/product_attachment/SK12V100-0915.pdf) it is 11.2 volt.

Comment: It came DOA. I guess, nothing to be done.

Comment: That's a bit 'light' as an answer as that would depend on discharge conditions cell type and size and more. I'll convert this to a comment BUT feel free to post another answer that is a superset of this one.

Comment: It may very possibly charge up OK and be OK BUT no new battery should come like that. Some suppliers suggest that a battery below 2.5V or even 3V/cell will have reduc3ed lifetimes - although many people discharge them to 2.5V/cell . If asking for a replacement is not too difficult I'd try that.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: do you want to add a fuller answer? Note that in that data sheet there are 3 low voltage limits with relevant conditions: 11.2V || > 10.4 V (50 ~ 150 ms) 
 (2.6V/Cell) || 11.6 V (2.9V/Cell) - some more detail would be useful.

Comment: If the battery gives you access to the balancing connections, you may be able to identify 3 good cells and one bad one. Doesn't solve your problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Opinions on maximum discharge vary, but I would not discharge beyond 2.8 V per cell (as always, it's a capacity/cycle life trade-off, but LiFePO<sub>4</sub> batteries have a very flat discharge curve at about 3.2 V per cell, and their voltage will only start dropping just before they are empty).

At 2.5 V per cell they are definitely empty; at 2 V per cell or below, they could well be damaged.

Even though your battery may be recoverable, I would return it as DOA.